# Para que serve o git send-email?

Tags: git, github, repository, gitlab

Estou precisando usar o git send-email para o envio de um exercício via email, porém, não consegui entender o intuito desse comando no git. Tem como enviar o repositório com os arquivos via email? Como funciona?

Comment: Ele serve para enviar *patches* (correções) por e-mail. Você não irá conseguir enviar arquivos ou o repositório compactado (*bundle*). Para usá-lo, você deve usar o comando `git format-patch` para preparar as correções antes de elas serem enviadas (escolher o *commit*, por exemplo). Para ver um exemplo do que vais receber no e-mail, execute o comando `git format-patch --stdout <commit hash>`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, seria legal você responder a pergunta no campo de respostas, não no de comentários, para podermos marcar como uma resposta correta, ou mesmo "rankear" se outros responderem!

Comment: @egomesbrandao De fato. Ocorre que, no momento que escrevi, não conseguiria fazer algo mais elaborado. Tentarei fazer uma resposta mais completa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por parte.

## Propósito do comando `send-email`

O GIT nasceu em um momento em que era muito comum programadores e entusiastas se reunirem em comunidades e fóruns para debater e programar. Apesar de existir softwares de versionamentos como o [Bitkeeper](https://www.bitkeeper.org/), não existia (até onde sei) um sistema integrado ao Git (lançando em 2005) como o Github, Gitlab e Bitbuket, por exemplo.

Em vez disso, alguns programadores utilizavam o comando `git send-email` para enviar correções e novos códigos através de protocolos SMTP. Com isso, eles podiam compartilhar seus códigos e ajudar a comunidade.

## Como o comando funciona?

Basicamente, ele envia uma coleção de correções feitas por você para um destinatário que vai poder mesclar as alterações.

O comando permite que possa ser enviado um dos dois tipos:

- Formato *mbox* (veremos adiante)
- Formato criado por Greg Kroah-hartman (Use por sua conta em risco, palavras do autor )

## É possível enviar anexos com o comando?

Não. Ele envia apenas texto. Caso queira enviar seu repositório por e-mail, basta usar o comando `git archive` ou `git bundle`.

## Como enviar correções via e-mail?

#### Requisitos

- Antes de mais nada, para os exemplos, irei utilizar um repositório aleatório: https://github.com/valdeirpsr/dotfiles
- Para servidor de e-mail, irei utilizar o [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/)
- Conhecimento básico de GIT

#### Preparando envio

Antes de fazer o envio, precisamos preparar as correções como no exemplo abaixo.

```bsh
git format-patch 0ac05bd5a72f8d4e6f2d7313689153851a4809e5

# Saída
# 0001-Update-.bash_aliases.patch
# 0002-Create-.functions.patch
```

> **Observação:** Para incluir um arquivo, use o comando `git format-patch --root -- <file>`

#### Conteúdo dos arquivos *.patch

Ao abrir ou imprimir o conteúdo do arquivo na tela, podemos ver que ele possui os cabeçalhos de e-mail (*FROM*, *SUBJECT*, *DATE*) e o corpo da mensagem informando onde ocorreram as alterações.

*OBS.:* Os comentários iniciados com *#* não existem no arquivo original e foram adicionados por motivos didáticos

```bsh
# Na linha abaixo temos o <commit-hash>
From 28f8dabbc894ec75a1d8bee86f9de18ad1e7ccd1 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001

# Informações autor
From: Valdeir S. <contact@valdeir.dev>

# Data de criação do <commit>
Date: Sat, 20 Mar 2021 16:17:48 -0300

# Assunto do <commit> (a primeira linha dele)
Subject: [PATCH 1/3] Update .bash_aliases

# Estatísticas das alterações
# Apresenta a quantidade de arquivos alterados, criados e deletados
# E a quantidade de caracteres removidos e adicionados
---
 .bash_aliases | 3 ---
 1 file changed, 3 deletions(-)

# Abaixo são destacadas as diferenças entre o snapshot anterior do arquivo com o atual
diff --git a/.bash_aliases b/.bash_aliases

# Index da árvore de trabalho.
# Compare `git show 450e3a9` com `git show 1cdcd5e`
index 450e3a9..1cdcd5e 100644
--- a/.bash_aliases
+++ b/.bash_aliases

# A linha iniciada com "-" significa que a linha foi removida
# A linha iniciada com "+" significa que a linha foi adicionada
# A linha iniciada SEM "-" e SEM "+" significa que não sofreu alterações
@@ -27,9 +27,6 @@ alias myip="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
 # Outros
 alias diff="git diff --no-index"

-# Comandos
-command -v calc >> /dev/null || function calc(){ awk "BEGIN{ print $* }" ;}
-
 # Finaliza todos os containers do Docker
 function dockerStopAll() {
   for c in $(docker ps | tail -n +2 | cut -d' ' -f1); do
--
2.31.1.windows.1
```

#### Enviando alterações

Para enviar as coleções de correções, você pode usar um serviço/servidor de SMTP.
No comando abaixo, definimos nossas configurações; no entanto, elas podem ser salvadas no arquivo `~/.gitconfig`

```bsh
git send-email \
  --smtp-encryption tls \
  --smtp-server smtp.mailtrap.io \
  --smtp-server-port 587 \
  --smtp-user <hash> \
  --smtp-pass <hash> \
  *.patch
```

#### Saída do comando

> ```
> # Lista de arquivos
> 0001-Update-.bash_aliases.patch
> 0002-Create-.functions.patch
> 0003-refactor-remove-o-arquivo-de-configura-o-do-navegado.patch
> (mbox) Adding cc: Valdeir S. <contact@valdeir.dev> from line 'From: Valdeir S. <contact@valdeir.dev>'
>
> # Cabeçalho e corpo do e-mail
> From: example@valdeir.dev
> To: exemplo@valdeir.dev
> Cc: Valdeir S. <contact@valdeir.dev>
> Subject: [PATCH 1/6] Update-.bash_aliases.patch
> Date: Mon, 12 Apr 2021 23:29:20 -0300
> Message-Id: <20210413022926.1198-1-example@valdeir.dev>
> X-Mailer: git-send-email 2.31.1.windows.1
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
>     The Cc list above has been expanded by additional
>     addresses found in the patch commit message. By default
>     send-email prompts before sending whenever this occurs.
>     This behavior is controlled by the sendemail.confirm
>     configuration setting.
>
>     For additional information, run 'git send-email --help'.
>     To retain the current behavior, but squelch this message,
>     run 'git config --global sendemail.confirm auto'.
>
> Send this email? ([y]es|[n]o|[e]dit|[q]uit|[a]ll):
> ```

Caso queira enviar as alterações, pressione <kbd>y</kbd> ou <kbd>a</kbd> e <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

## Para que serve o comando `format-patch`

Ele é o responsável por preparar os arquivos por *commit* já com os cabeçalhos necessários e o a saída do comando `git diff <commit B>..<commit A>`.

## O que é *MBOX*?

De acordo com a documentação do [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mbox), o MBOX é "um arquivo de texto que contém um número arbitrário de mensagens de e-mail. Cada mensagem consiste em um carimbo do correio, seguido por uma mensagem de e-mail formatado de acordo com RFC822 e RFC2822. As linhas são separadas por caracteres de alimentação de linha (ASCII 10)."

## Alguém, em sã consciência, usa isso?

Esta é a única forma de contribuir com alguns projetos como o Kernel do Linux ou o próprio GIT.

Caso alguém tenha interesse em contribuir com o Kernel ou apenas queira saber como fazer, basta acessar a página [Enviando correções: o guia essencial para o guia essencial para colocar seu código no kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/submitting-patches.html)

## Exemplo de configuração no arquivo `~/.gitconfig`

```
[sendemail]
    smtpEncryption = tls
    smtpServer = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpUser = you@email.com
    smtpServerPort = 587
    smtpPass = Your-pass (Não é recomendável)
    confirm = auto
    replyTo = reply@email.com
```

## Mais informações

- https://dev.to/valdeirpsr/para-que-serve-o-comando-git-send-email-1nbk

## Referências

- https://gist.github.com/valdeirpsr/138771b722168f8bd1bd98ff407b7c0f
- https://public-inbox.org/git/
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/805
- https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project
- https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Come%C3%A7ando-Uma-Breve-Hist%C3%B3ria-do-Git
- https://github.com/gregkh/kroah.com/blob/master/linux/send_lots_of_email.pl
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch/
- https://www.cisco.com/c/pt_br/support/docs/security/email-security-appliance/117912-qa-cdc-00.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox

Comment: Caso tenham sugestões (e principalmente correções de ortografia, pontuação etc) aceito.. 00h12m 

Comment: Acho que agora você teve tempo! Muito bom!!! :D